# What is it about Twilight Struggle that keeps it so consistently highly rated on BGG?

Tags: twilight-struggle

Some say it's due to BGG being full of people who lived through the Cold War, adding a certain nostalgic element, but perhaps someone who has played it can offer some further insight.

Comment: A question like this is likely to get many different answers that are all "correct".  On BGG that might be a good question, but around here we usually like questions that have a single, objective answer.